# SQL Server : update using an aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have coded the following in a stored procedure but it is not working how I anticipated

```
UPDATE  dbo.products
SET     stock = t.totalquantity
FROM    dbo.products
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT accountdetail.itemnumber ,
                        SUM(accountdetail.quantity + products.stock) totalquantity
                 FROM   accountdetail ,
                        products
                 WHERE  accountdetail.orderid = @accountorderid
                        AND dbo.products.itemnumber = accountdetail.itemnumber
                 GROUP BY accountdetail.itemnumber
               ) t ON dbo.products.itemnumber = t.itemnumber
```

The code works fine if there is only 1 item number with a quantity but if there are 2 of the same item numbers with quantities the result ends up being incorrect

eg

- products.stock = 4
- accountdetail.duantity = 2 from one itemnumber
- products.stock = 6 - This is correct
- products.stock = 4
- accountdetail.duantity = 2 from two itemnumbers the same
- products.stock = 12 - This is incorrect and I need help in understanding what is going wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it.

Take out the products in the ()

and do you join outside of the ()

```
UPDATE dbo.products
SET    stock = t.totalquantity + stock
FROM   dbo.products
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT accountdetail.itemnumber ,
                        SUM(accountdetail.quantity) totalquantity
                 FROM   accountdetail
                 WHERE  accountdetail.orderid = @accountorderid
                 GROUP BY accountdetail.itemnumber
               ) t ON dbo.products.itemnumber = t.itemnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
with cte as (
   select a.itemnumber, sum(a.quantity) as totalquantity
   from accountdetail as a
   where a.orderid = @accountorderid
   group by a.itemnumber
)
update dbo.products set
    stock = stock + t.totalquantity
from dbo.products as p
    inner join cte as t on c.itemnumber = p.itemnumber
```